# getting highly confused by odd behaviour of viewController Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have overrided a method as

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    // creating bottom line for textField
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailTextField.frame.size.height - width, width:  emailTextField.frame.size.width, height: emailTextField.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
        emailTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

Now whats happening is that when I run my app on Iphone 6, 6+ every thing works fine. But when I run the same code on `iphone5` (Simulator + real Device ) `viewDidLayoutSubViews` is getting called infinite times and my app becoms unresponsive. I solved the problem by using a bool variable. But I do not understand why is this happening. So can someone please explain this to me.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As docs says that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method need for change layout

> Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out
>   its subviews. When the bounds change for a view controller's view,
>   the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system
>   calls this method. However, this method being called does not indicate
>   that the individual layouts of the view's subviews have been
>   adjusted. Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.

Move your code to `viewDidLoad` method or to `loadView` if you are not using `xibs` or `Storyboards`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // creating bottom line for textField
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailTextField.frame.size.height - width, width:  emailTextField.frame.size.width, height: emailTextField.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
        emailTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

If you would like to change `border.frame` you can set it to class variable and change it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      self.border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailTextField.frame.size.height - width, width:  emailTextField.frame.size.width, height: emailTextField.frame.size.height)
      self.border.borderWidth = width    
}
```

Comment: actually problem is solved, But what I do not understand is why the app does not stuck on iphone 6 and 6+  why only on iphone 5 ?

Comment: I think the diff between iOS versions and ram memory limits in devices

Comment: @UmairAfzal your issue is not solved. You are using a very bad practise to solve this problem, blocking the method from running is never the right choice. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is for positioning views, not creating and adding them. Please move this code to viewDidLoad as suggested above. You will run into this problem every time otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

with this:

```
emailTextField.addSublayer(border)
```

-> you want to add sublayer to a view - as you want to apply `masksToBounds` property to it either.

Answer (score 0):

Move your implementation inside viewDidLayoutSubviews. I got the same issue. Hope it will work.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
 //Your CODE    
}
```